# MultiLineStringZ in QGIS 3D view

Tags: qgis, linestring, 3d-map, z-value

I have a point layer with Z values that I display in the 3D view of QGIS. I want to display the trajectory of those points as a line layer, like in Google Earth. Therefore I converted my PointZ layer into a MultiLineStringZ layer with following treatments :

- Points to path
- Explode lines
- Join attributes by location with my PointZ layer which has Z value as attribute
- Set Z value with new created Z field

which gives me a MultiLineStringZ. But when I display this layer in the 3D view of QGIS (after I defined its symbology for 3D view in the layer properties), I only get its projection on the ground. But it works fine with PointZ layer.

Btw : I know the [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointstopaths_v02/) "Points to path**S**" which allows to keep attributes to every edges of the new paths but I can't get it work on my data. If you have any ideas or experiences with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

- In the Properties dialog for the vector layer, go to '3D View'
- Choose 'Single Symbol' at the top
- Put a checkmark in the "Render as simple 3D lines" checkbox

You may also have to export your vector data to a different format; I found that an imported Wkt textfile didn't work, but after exporting to Gpkg it did work.

The documentation at https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/3d_map_view.html#d-vector-layers is a little out-of-date; it seems to refer to the "Render as simple 3D lines" checkbox as "Enable 3D Renderer"